# Tableau sorting by value from measure

Tags: sorting, tableau-api

I have a measure in Tableau that has values a,b,c and a field of countries that each have varying values of a,b,c.

I want to make a sort that allows you to select either a,b, or c, and then ranks the countries accordingly by their value of a,b,or c.

I have tried to do a parameter to calculated field, but that doesn't work because that method is for sorting between measures, not values of measures.

Comment: Can you please share screenshots ?

Comment: Did my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a parameter and calculated field--what have you tried that didn't work?

```
[sort parameter]
A string value with allowable values of a, b, or c
```

If a, b, and c are each their own measure:

```
[sort field]
IF [sort parameter] = 'a' then
    [a]
ELSEIF [sort parameter] = 'b' then
    [b]
ELSE
    [c]
END
```

If values of a, b, and c are in one measure (perhaps called [value]) and a separate column exists to distinguish (perhaps called [type]):

```
[sort field]
IF [sort parameter] = 'a' then
    SUM(IIF([type] = 'a',[value],NULL)
ELSEIF [sort parameter] = 'b' then
    SUM(IIF([type] = 'b',[value],NULL)
ELSE
    SUM(IIF([type] = 'c',[value],NULL)
END
```

Sort your visualization by [sort field].

Comment: I have the first case but when I sort my [sort field] and choose option a in my filter, the sorting falls out when I choose option b. It doesn't sort dynamically by chose measure. How do I overcome this?